# Remove everything within a div besides span elements

Tags: jquery

How can i remove the `null` word inside the div with id `items`? I want to remove everything besides span elements.

```js
$('#items').contents(':not(span)').remove();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="items" class="w3-xxlarge" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate w3-xxlarge w3-text-blue"></span>null</div>
```

Comment: Can you wrap that `NULL` to some element?

Comment: no because it is generated dynamically at the end

Comment: @freedomn-m doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `html()` and pass a function parameter that only returns the `<span>`

```js
//Replace all contents with the span.
$('#items').html(function(){
     return $(this).find('span'); 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="items" class="w3-xxlarge" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate w3-xxlarge w3-text-blue"></span>null</div>
```

---

If you only want to remove the text *null*

```js
$('#items').html(function() {
  return $(this).html().replace('null', '');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="items" class="w3-xxlarge"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate w3-xxlarge w3-text-blue"></span>null</div>
```

Comment: this function made some problems on the style of that area with the div

Comment: What is the problem? @GragasIncoming This function will only return the span. If you need to return other elements, what elements do you want to return?

Comment: no spaces and padding, smaller text, something is going wrong on my code

Comment: Maybe there are something else besides the `<span>`. If you only want to remove the text null, I added a code @GragasIncoming

Comment: i would appreciate if you could remove word null before outputting on click. Code is here:https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQEL9L4Y6CES

Comment: You mean remove the `null` on the button? Like: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQELAD8YBEOG

Comment: no, in the `html()` before outputted, `null` should be removed. I tried `.html("Word null ").replace('null', '');`

Comment: @GragasIncoming I don't understand.

Comment: @GragasIncoming Do you mean.. Like this? https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQEP6JH91VKE

Comment: exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```js
var html = $(' #items > *');//get elements except the text in the #items div
$('#items').html(html);//append them back to the element
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="items" class="w3-xxlarge" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate w3-xxlarge w3-text-blue"></span>null</div>
```